# How to view webfont files (ttf, woff, woff2, eot) on a mac?

Tags: web-fonts, file-format, mac

Does anyone know how to view webfont file formats (ttf, woff, woff2, eot) on a Mac?

I've been sent some files and would like to view them so I can make sure all the formats are correct.

Comment: FontForge is free and supports woff since 2019 https://github.com/fontforge/fontforge/releases

Answer (score 13):

If you also want to preview unicode characters and specs, this one is very good:

[FontDrop!](https://fontdrop.info/)

Comment: fwiw doesn't support woff2

Answer (score 6):

There is a [QuickLook plugin](https://github.com/Nyx0uf/qlwoff) that lets you preview .woff from within finder. Finder should be able to preview .ttf natively. I'm not sure this is enough for testing. You can take a look and verify they are working fonts, but not much more.

Another option is a [Drag & Drop font testing page](https://github.com/impallari/font-testing-page) from Pablo Impallari. Drag the fonts from your desktop and you can see kerning, character support, opentype features  and more.

**Edit sept 2018**: Impallari's page is down, but there are other options like [Vernon Adam's testing page](http://vernnobile.github.io/webfont-testing/), the [Cyreal version](http://www.cyreal.org/Font-Testing-Page/index.php), [Musictypefoundry's mirror](https://www.musictypefoundry.com/text-font-testing/index.php) or you can [self-host](https://github.com/impallari/Font-Testing-Page) from the source

Comment: That font testing page looks good!

Comment: That is excellent thanks.  The slight downside being it doesn't support .eot which is the one I really wanted to check, but a great find nonetheless.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

#### 1. Use a font manager.

I use [FontExplorer X Pro](http://www.fontexplorerx.com/) and have no trouble viewing web fonts. The newest version has some new web specific features for simulating different OS and browsers for seeing how your webfont will look on different systems. Any decent font manager should let you see web fonts, at least to some degree (FontBook is not a decent font manager).

#### 2. Set up a test webpage.

Just make a regular HTML page with everything you want to test, include the font in your CSS using `@font-face` as you normally would and open the local file in your browser—no need to upload to the internet or anything like that. Although having a local development server is a good idea.

Comment: Hi Cai,
I want to take a quick look at .eot files (used for <IE 9 ) as well as the others and I don't have that browser.

Comment: Well, using a font manager would be the best option. There are probably plugins similar to the one @spiral linked to but for .eot files, I'll have a look when I have a bit more time later.

Answer (score 2):

I was also looking for a solution. After trying many options, https://transfonter.org/ is what worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this; great service. Just helped me standardize and make sense of a bunch of font files I'd been provided which had cryptic filenames. They should update it and add support for the `font-display` css directive

Answer (score 2):

This works perfectly for WOFF, WOFF2, OTF and TTF files

https://fontsee.com/

Answer (score 1):

In addition, if you need to open and edit font files, or convert them, some online services can't do this from the .eot format. A tool that can is Fontlab's [TransType](https://www.fontlab.com/font-converter/transtype/).

Comment: Cannot open WOFF2 files, only WOFF files.